# Please identify temple in this photo

Tags: temple, identification-request, architecture

I wish to paint following in future.

What temple is this?

Where is it located?

Here is the webpage I found it, https://www.aryagezi.com/gezi/204/tum-renkleri-ile-nepal-ve-hindistan

[image]

Comment: compare this 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amer_Fort#/media/File:Amber_Fort-Jaipur-India0007.JPG

Comment: Amer Fort is a fort located in Amer, Rajasthan, India. (More Info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amer_Fort )

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya It should an answer. It is more detailed than existing answer.

Comment: This is not a temple. It's a fort. So it's unrelated to Hinduism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amber Fort, Jaipur.
Lot of pics of it around.